# How to get the name of a property in python

Tags: python, properties, attributes

How do you get the name of a property in python? Any suggestions welcome.

For functions and methods it is as simple as `f.__name__`.

But properties do not have the `__name__` attribute.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12654947/8286364) answers your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The property does not have a name, but you are probably really looking for the name of its `fget` attribute, which (ignoring any shuffling done after the fact) will be the name of the class attribute to which the `property` instance is bound.

```
class A:
    @property
    def foo(self):
        return 3


assert A.foo.fget.__name__ == "foo"
```

Comment: Worked great. Thanks! Strange that properties don't have names.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the parent class, `dir()`, `vars()`, and primarily `__dict__()` are what you are looking for. If you only have the attribute itself, outside of the context of a class, then I believe you can't.